# FormGroup return a empty string

Tags: angular, formgroups

I'm doing a project in angular I'm using the FormGroup to get the value of an input but it always returns an empty value ("")

html:

```
          <input formControlName="message" type="text">
          <button (click)="login()" type="button">Publicar</button>
        </form>
```

TS:

```
  data = {
    formgroup: new FormGroup({
      message: new FormControl("")
    })
  }


  login() {
    console.log(this.data.formgroup.controls.login);
    console.log(this.data.formgroup.controls);
    console.log(this.data.formgroup);
  }
```

Comment: Have you imported the ReactiveFormsModule? Have you added the formgroup to the form in the template (<form [formGroup]="data?.formgroup">)? Also, why have you wrapped the formgroup in an object?

Answer (score 0):

`data` should be a new `FormGroup()`